# Does base64 encoding has any string length limit to encode?

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding, base64

I have tab application which converts password using Base64 encoding. It is send to web application via web service where it gets decoded. Code for decoding is,

```
public static string DecryptStringPassword(string base64StringToDecrypt)
        {
            //Set up the encryption objects
            using (AesCryptoServiceProvider acsp = GetProvider(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Key)))
            {
                byte[] RawBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64StringToDecrypt);
                ICryptoTransform ictD = acsp.CreateDecryptor();

                //RawBytes now contains original byte array, still in Encrypted state

                //Decrypt into stream
                MemoryStream msD = new MemoryStream(RawBytes, 0, RawBytes.Length);
                CryptoStream csD = new CryptoStream(msD, ictD, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                //csD now contains original byte array, fully decrypted

                //return the content of msD as a regular string
                return (new StreamReader(csD)).ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        private static AesCryptoServiceProvider GetProvider(byte[] key)
        {
            AesCryptoServiceProvider result = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            result.BlockSize = 128;
            result.KeySize = 128;
            result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            result.GenerateIV();
            result.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            byte[] RealKey = GetKey(key, result);
            result.Key = RealKey;
            // result.IV = RealKey;
            return result;
        }

        private static byte[] GetKey(byte[] suggestedKey, SymmetricAlgorithm p)
        {
            byte[] kRaw = suggestedKey;
            List<byte> kList = new List<byte>();

            for (int i = 0; i < p.LegalKeySizes[0].MinSize; i += 8)
            {
                kList.Add(kRaw[(i / 8) % kRaw.Length]);
            }
            byte[] k = kList.ToArray();
            return k;
        }
```

Is there any maximum character limit for base64 encoding? For one of the passwords "xwYgqg8+xnynU7MpceOoJw==" is the encrypted string which gives exception "padding is invalid and can not be removed" while decoding using above code.
In the DecryptStringPassword() function, last line, 
return (new StreamReader(csD)).ReadToEnd(); gives the exception.

Same password I encrypted using AES encryption, it gives me 
"xwYgqg8+xnynU7MpceOoJ70HuRIIw+OkcDPBVa18mLw=" such a big encrypted password compared to base64 encoding which does not give any exception while decoding.

Is there any limit that base64 encoding gives always 24 characters long encrypted string or any length restriction on the string to be encrypted.

Our one of the users facing this issue while decoding the password. Rest all users have no problem while decoding.

Comment: "padding is invalid and can not be removed" is a message relating to *encryption* (here, AES), not related to base 64 *encoding*.

Comment: This clearly is an XY problem, but I don't see any reason to close it because of that.

Comment: **Warning** the methods `GetProvider` and `GetKey` both display horrible cryptographic practices and should not be used (repetition of key material, static IV's, badly named / unnecessary variables, the unnecessary use of lists for key material, etc.). Using `Encoding.Default.GetBytes` to get the key bytes is a terrible idea as well, keys are not strings.

Answer (score 2):

No limits to the string to be encoded ("encryption" is a different process) and no limit on the result that depends on how many characters you put in (consider that base64 is used to encode the body of files sent throught http, so, no limits).

The padding the error is referring to are those `=` appended to the end of the string. The Base64 encoding takes your original message, divides it in bytes and then groups the bit stream in segments of 6 bits before converting it to an alphanumeric representation. Those `=` are added when the bit length of your message is not divisible by 6.

My guess is that something is happening to that string before it reaches `Convert.FromBase64String` or the base64 encoding (missing in your sample) does not even work.

I'd write a minimal example with just the base64 encoding/decoding to verify that this part is working.

Comment: Ok understood encoding and encryption are different processes. Encryption needs a Key for decryption to return plain text again where encoding does not need any Key (Is this correct?). In that case then I mistook the above process. In my case its base64 encryption since code is using a key to encrypt and decrypt. So in case of encryption, will it be same problem you have stated (something is happening to that string before it reaches Convert.FromBase64String or the base64 encoding (missing in your sample) does not even work).

Comment: My encryption code (ipad app) is following,   + (NSString *) EncryptString:(NSString *)plainSourceStringToEncrypt   {   StringEncryption *crypto = [[[StringEncryption alloc] init] autorelease];  NSData *_secretData = [plainSourceStringToEncrypt dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];  NSData *encryptData = [ crypto encrypt:_secretData Key:[_key dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] padding:&padding];  return [encryptedData base64EncodingWithLineLength:0];  }

Comment: Partially right, with encoding you are expressing some data with a different format (in this case from the usual format with 8bits characters to base64 where every character is just 6bits with characters include in a-Z and 0-9 and with optional "=" padding), while encryption translate a message to a new message applying a key in some form **with an algorithm with a varying degree of complexity to hide what is contained**. Completely different.
You there are first decoding from Base64 to a byte stream and THEN decrypting with the symmetric AES algorithm.

Comment: The objective-c code does the right steps in the right order, but I'm not so sure about all those different `dataUsingEncoding`, could be a source of issue if they use non ascii chars in their string (IF it is not already the source of your issue).
What is that `StringEncryption `? Does it work? Are you using CommonCrypto?

Comment: Hi I am not sure about swift code so not sure about StringEncryption or CommonCrypto